# How long (milliseconds) does it take to show the services, when device BLE connects to mobile BLE?

Tags: android, embedded, bluetooth-lowenergy

An embedded device will send data through BLE. I developed an Android application to receive data, but have the following problem:

When the device connects to mobile BLEit will send data immediately but I am not able to read data, if I give a delay  the app starts reading characteristics but will not be collecting data.

So when device BLE connects to mobile BLE how many milliseconds will it take to show the services? So I can match delay and receive data.

Comment: Your question seems to be "how long does it take for two devices to connect to each other". How exactly do you expect an answer to that question?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of manually setting delays, you can use onConnectionStateChange, and onServicesDiscovered callbacks to execute your code based on the connection stage.